# Adding a comment in alter command in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am adding a column in oracle and I also want to add comments to describe the column. 
Here's my syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD (ColumnName  VARCHAR(10) null COMMENT ON tableName.columnName IS 'some comments');
```

Her's the error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Isn't it two statements that you're trying to run as one ? `ALTER TABLE TableName ADD ColumnName  VARCHAR(10) null;` and  `COMMENT ON tableName.columnName IS 'some comments');` ?

Comment: You cannot do it in a single statement.

Comment: @alfasin, I am not sure if that counts as two statements since am new to oracle. So, what's the right way of doing it?

Comment: Try running only the following: `COMMENT ON tableName.columnName IS 'some comments'`

Comment: I I separate it into two statements and run it, it gives me the following erorr: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-32594: invalid object category for COMMENT command
32594. 00000 -  "invalid object category for COMMENT command"
*Cause:    The object category specified is not a valid object for which to
           use the COMMENT command.
*Action:   Retry the COMMENT command by specifying an accepted object
           category. (ie, Table, Operator, Indextype, etc.)
1:19 PM

Comment: @jonearls, it is not a duplicate!

Comment: @Stranger Woops, sorry about that.  I retracted my close vote.  David's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax is well documented: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4009.htm

```
comment on column schema.table.column is 'some comment';
```